# Cross Validation and Sequential Monte Carlo (SMC)

Tags: cross-validation, inference, credible-interval, particle-filter

Please bear with me, I am not a statistician. 
I have a likelihood

$$\Pr (d|\vec{x},\vec{e})$$

where $d$ is a single datum, $\vec{x}$ are the model parameters, and $\vec{e}$ are known experiment parameters.
For each of a fixed set of experiment parameters $\{e_1,...,e_L\}$ I have $N=400$ data samples, $d_{l,n}\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $1\leq l\leq L$ and $1\leq n\leq N$.
All $L$ experiments are required to break the degeneracy of $\vec{x}$.

I am using sequential monte carlo (SMC) particle filter to infer the value of $\vec{x}$.
This is not being used online, I have access to all of the data at once. I end up with a posterior described by a particle approximation
$$\Pr(\vec{x}|\{d_{l,n}\})=\sum_{i=1}^{I}w_i\delta(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_i)$$
and therefore an estimate

$$\hat{x}=\sum_{i=1}^I w_i\vec{x}_i.$$

It seems to work well; the mean of the posterior when simulated with the model gives great fits (visually).

I am interested in doing some kind of cross-validation of this estimator. I want to make sure that the posterior is not over-fit. Basically, that a credible region derived from the posterior is, in fact, credible. I am thinking along the lines of dividing the $N$ data sets into disjoint collections, running SMC on each, and seeing if each of the estimates agree with the other posteriors, but I don't know exactly how to do this.

My question is: is there a standard thing to do in this situation? What would you recommend?